# Html2Canvas rendering only half of my screen

Tags: angular, html2canvas

Html2canvas rendering only half of the screen in angular application and other half filled with white space. I tried it by importing the plugin directly into the index.html and also by importing from node package but nothing works. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.[Attached image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG6bK.png)

Comment: You need to provide some Code sample as well in order to be more understandable

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was reverting to version `1.0.0-rc.1`. RC2 had a big TypeScript rewrite and apparently introduced some pretty major scaling issues.

There are also a handful of relevant issues about this:

- [#1900](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1900#issuecomment-504422179)
- [#1964](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1964)

Another issue could be a limitation from the canvas size. A [known workaround](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/882#issuecomment-428569160) for this is to explicitly blow up your canvas in size:

```
html2canvas(el, {height: 3000, width: 3000})
```